# Perform RollingUpdate using Cloudformation with Spot Instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-elb, autoscaling

I am using cloudformation [UpdatePolicy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html) attribute to perform a rolling update in case of any change to my ec2 launch configuration. This works fine while using on demand instances. But when I use spot instances I get below error:

```
Autoscaling rolling updates cannot be performed because the current launch configuration is using spot instances and MinInstancesInService is greater than zero.
```

Setting `MinInstancesInService` property to zero make it work but then I get around 3-5 min downtime.

Is there a way to achieve this without the downtime using Cloudformation? If not can someone point towards a better way to automate this rolling update process as I have multiple environments and doing it manually is very error prone. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set `MinInstancesInService` to anything other than 0 when using spot instances, because spot instances can be terminated at any time, thus making it impossible for AWS to guarantee a minimum number of instances to be kept in service during the rolling update.

However, you can set the [`MaxBatchSize`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html#cfn-attributes-updatepolicy-rollingupdate-maxbatchsize) param in your UpdatePolicy to 1, so only one instance will be updated at a time. To ensure high availability, you must make sure there are 2 or more instances available in your AutoScalingGroup, otherwise the rolling update will terminate your single instance, resulting in downtime.